# Where should questions which are directly related to SuperUser problems be placed?

Tags: discussion

Where should questions which are directly related to SuperUser problems be placed?

First such question I found out about is [this](https://superuser.com/questions/171876/) one. It seems to be related to Super User so SuperUser looks like a logical place to ask it, but on the other hand it's about web service and we agreed that such questions aren't welcome.

So what I'm asking is which of these four option is correct:

Question is related to SuperUser and should be asked on SuperUser.

Question is related to SuperUser and should be asked on Meta because it's about a web-service and is off-topic on SuperUser.

Question is related to a webservice and is off-topic and should be closed.

Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's closed and I referred the person to our web related SE-sites

Comment: That's OK for this one particular question, but do you think that's the correct procedure in general? It'd be nice to have a reference for future cases.

Comment: Until the websites are out of beta, they are off-topic and will be closed. End of story :-(